# Getting a null value of input fields on mobile, but getting value on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am setting some values of input fields in local storage through JavaScript, it is working fine on desktop but when i check it on mobile i am getting null values.

Here is my code:

```js
function reserve() {
  let date = document.getElementById("start").value;
  alert(date)
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="date" id="start" placeholder="Move Date">
<a href="/request"><input type="button" name="" value="Reserve Now" onclick="reserve()"></a>
```

Now i am getting null on mobile but get a value in alert on desktop.

Comment: Even if the user has selected a date?

Comment: I tried the above code in mobile Chrome and mobile Safari, and it displayed the selected date in both.

Comment: If I don't select a date, it displays a blank alert, not `null`.

Comment: Yes, I said "mobile Chrome" and "mobile Safari". I tested on an iPhone.

Comment: But i am getting null.

Comment: What browser and version?

Comment: You have two `id="start"` on your page. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: @Barmar Even if they had two, they can never get `null` from an input.

Comment: **You must not have interactive elements nested**, so you cannot have the button sit inside a link element.